# laravel cron job is not running on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I am trying to run a cron job on cPanel with the following command but I am unable to run it:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/innohygn/job.graystork.com/admin/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This is what I have tried:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $tasksLog = storage_path('/logs/tasks-output.log');
    
    $schedule->call(new EmailApplicantProfileProgress())
        ->everyMinute()
        ->appendOutputTo($tasksLog);

    Log::info('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be two possible explanations for this problem.

Firstly, since you're not seeing any output, you might not have the right permissions to write to **storage/logs/**. Have you checked them?

Secondly, maybe you're not setting your cron job right. You need to set that command running every minute, as mentioned in the [Starting The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction) docs.

To set it running all the time, in your server's terminal run `crontab -e`.
On the editor that opens, write the following line:

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/innohygn/job.graystork.com/admin/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Save and close the cron editor, and wait a minute or two before you see any output in your logs.